# angular foreach update object property

Tags: arrays, angularjs, foreach

So am using angular foreach as below

```
        $scope.section = [{
      "id": 1,
      "name": "name1",
      "value": "foo1"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "name 2",
      "value": "foo2"
    }]

    angular.forEach(section, function(item, key) {
        if(item.value)  {
            item.value = 'Some New value'
            }
    });
```

For some reason it doesnt work plus if I try to manipulate I get an error about duplicate value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This work for me, i just add scope.section on the forEach

```
 $scope.section = [{
      "id": 1,
      "name": "name1",
      "value": "foo1"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "name 2",
      "value": "foo2"
    }]
angular.forEach($scope.section, function(item, key) {
    if(item.value)  {
        item.value = 'Some New value';
        console.log('new value');
        }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Convert this

```
angular.forEach(section, function(item, key) {
```

To this

```
angular.forEach($scope.section, function(item, key) {
```

<kbd>**[`DEMO`](https://jsfiddle.net/aiubian/2dwtu2us/3/)**</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

You are forgot add `$scope` in object

```js
var jimApp = angular.module("mainApp",  []);

jimApp.controller('mainCtrl', function($scope){
  
  $scope.section = [{ "id": 1, "name": "name1", "value": "foo1" },
                    { "id": 2, "name": "name 2", "value": "foo2" }];

    angular.forEach($scope.section, function(item, key) {
        if(item.value)  {
            item.value = 'Some New value'
        }
    });

  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="mainApp" ng-controller="mainCtrl">
  {{section}}
</div>
```